# How to iterate through a list of strings in json using java

Tags: java, json, loops

I have to iterate through a List of Mapper and maper is a list of strings, my json looks like:

{
"aa":{
"val":"",
"agl":
[
{
"a": "A1",
"b": "B1",
"c": "C1"
},
{
"a": "A2",
"b": "B2",
"c": "C2"
}
]
}
}

The result is to get a,b and c values with iterator mode.
I tried this the code below but i have the same error **JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject**

```
List<Mapper> agl= fileDescription.get("aa").getAgl();
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(agl);

      System.out.println(jsonArray);
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        Object jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
       
        System.out.println(jsonObj);

       }
```

I tried also this code but it don't give me the result i need:

```
 Iterator iterator = agl.iterator();

      while (iterator.hasNext()) {

      System.out.println(iterator.next());

      System.out.println( iterator1.getA());
```

**Mapper.java**

```
public class Mapper{

@JsonProperty("a")
private String a;

@JsonProperty("b")
private  String b;

@JsonProperty("c")
private String c;

public String getA() {
return a;
}

public void setA(String a) {
  this.a= a;
}

public String getB() {
  return b;
}

public void setB(String b) {
this.b= b;
}

public String getC() {
return c;
}

public void setC(String c) {
this.c= c;
}


@Override
public String toString() {

return "{\"a\":" + "\""+a+ "\"" + ", \"b\":" + "\"" + b + "\"" + ", \"c\":" + "\"" + c + "\"" + "}";
 }
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the correct list? What does `agl` or `jsonArray` contain? Can you show a [mcve] that includes parsing the json?

Comment: jsonArray contains: ["{\"a\":\"A1\", \"b\": \"B1\", \"c\": \"C1\" }","{\"a\":\"A2\",\"b\":\"B2\",\"c\": \"C2\"}"]

Comment: Alright, well, that's a list with a single element, a string, not an object, so again, please show a [mcve] of the full code including the mapper class

Comment: it's not a single element, there a are 2 elements in my json example. I updated the post with the code of Mapper

Comment: Still waiting for you to show the `agl= ...` code because apparently you are getting a list of strings, not objects, as the error says

Comment: it is done. yes it is a list of strings and i want to access to these strings and their values

Comment: It should **not** be a list of strings, though. It should be a list of objects... For example, this would work fine, and you shouldn't need to create a new JSONArray `for (Mapper m: agl) { System.out.println(m.getA()); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misusing the type system. You already have a valid list to iterate. Don't create another one

```
List<Mapper> agl= fileDescription.get("aa").getAgl();
Iterator<Mapper> iterator = agl.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Mapper m = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(m.getA());
}
```

Or simply

```
List<Mapper> agl= fileDescription.get("aa").getAgl();
for (Mapper m : agl) {
    System.out.println(m.getA());
}
```

Or `agl.forEach(m -> System.out.println(m.getA()));`